# How to make a button touch sensitive

Tags: ios, swift, button, touch, action

I'm pretty new in iOS and I couldn't figure out how to make a button that activates whenever:

1. The finger passes on it
2. The finger press on it

Comment: Share your code that you tried!

Comment: aIBAction func prova(_ sender: Any) {
        (sender as! UIButton).backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    }
    //drag exit
    aIBAction func prova1(_ sender: Any) {
        (sender as! UIButton).backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    }
    //drag enter
    aIBAction func prova2(_ sender: Any) {
        (sender as! UIButton).backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    }
    //touch down
    aIBAction func prova3(_ sender: Any) {
        (sender as! UIButton).backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    }


I tried what was the best for me but non of them are the point number 1

Comment: So you are not getting callback in any of these methods? Did you connect the button with these actions in storyboard/xib?

Comment: that's not the problem, they work fine but they don't work as I want them to work, they should activate when:
1. The finger passes on it
2. The finger press on it

Answer (score 0):

### PAN: When the finger passes on it

You can simply add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` recognizer and then detect when the is UIButton, this would mean the finger is passing along.

```
@IBAction func handlePan(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .Began || gestureRecognizer.state == .Changed {

        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translationInView(self.view)  
        // note: 'view' is optional and need to be unwrapped
        gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPointMake(gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x + translation.x, gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y)  
        gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPointMake(0,0), inView: self.view)  
    }  
}
```

### TAP: When finger presses on it

You can use the `IBAction` from storyboard or add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the button and then create a handle function in a similar fashion.

Hope this helps!

Comment: gives me errore on CGPointMake. It says it doesn't exist in swift

Comment: My bad.  So In swift 4, change your CGPointMake(startX, startY) to CGPoint(x: startX, y: startY)